# stack level too deep 'create' rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

hi all iam new to rails , iam trying to upload pdf and i worte a create and validate function only to accept pdfs but after i click submit its keep on rendering doesnt return anything or validate the file but it save the uploaded file correctly also its accepting any type of files.

my controller.rb

```
class PdfController < ApplicationController
  
  def index
  end
     
  def create
      #@pdf = Pdf.new(pdf_params)
      @pdf = Pdf.new(pdf_params)

      if @pdf.save
        redirect_to @pdf, notice: 'Pdf was successfully uploaded.' and return
      else
        render 'new' and return
      end
  end

  def new
    @pdf = Pdf.new
  end

  def show
     @pdf = Pdf.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def set_pdf
    @pdf = Pdf.find(params[:id])
  end

  def pdf_params
    #params.require(:pdf).permit(:attachment)
    params.permit(:attachment)
  end

  def check_file_type
    if attachment.attached? && !attachment.content_type.in?(%w( application/pdf))
        errors.add(:attachment, 'Must be a PDF file')
    end
   end
end
```

model.rb

```
class Pdf < ActiveRecord::Base
   #has_many_attached :attachment
   has_one_attached :attachment
   #before_save :check_file_type
   validate :check_file_type ,  on: :save
   #validates :attachment, :presence=>true , content_type: ['application/pdf']
   #validates :attachment, file_content_type: { allow: [/^pdf\/.*/] }
   #validates :attachment, :attachment_content_type => { :content_type => ['application/pdf']}
   validates :attachment, attached: true, content_type: { in: 'application/pdf', message: 'is not a PDF' }

   
   def attachment1
       attachment_path = "#{Dir.tmpdir}/#{attachment.filename}"
       File.open(attachment_path, 'wb') do |file|
        file.write(attachment.download)
       end   
   end


   private 

   def check_file_type
      if attachment.attached? && !attachment.content_type.in?(%w(application/pdf))
          errors.add(:attachment, 'Must be a PDF file')
      end
   end
end
```

form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag({action: :create}, multipart: true) do %>
   <%= file_field_tag 'pdf_file' %>
   <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

logs :

```
Started POST "/pdf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-08-06 19:57:58 +0530
Processing by PdfController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"0uBffj57MCwiDYVhUoh3i1Dhil6Ept6v/gm7Pmk6VPvzIj1yY2ssAFPo6zGBA2716VhYnv3QVnS0qEzpiTMG+Q==", "pdf"=>{"attachment"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000056475ce6ee08 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20200806-5019-qme0u2.pdf>, @original_filename="icinga2_advanced_1.6.0-handouts.pdf", @content_type="application/pdf", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pdf[attachment]\"; filename=\"icinga2_advanced_1.6.0-handouts.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">}, "commit"=>"submit"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 158ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 66024)


  
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):

app/models/pdf.rb:13:in `attachment'
app/models/pdf.rb:13:in `attachment'
app/models/pdf.rb:13:in `attachment'
app/models/pdf.rb:23:in `check_file_type'
app/controllers/pdf_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

someone help me with this please

Comment: What does your attachment model look like?

Comment: What is the `attachment1` method?

Comment: iam trying to upload pdf file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `active_storage_validations` gem.

Following rule is already validating the content type.

```rb
validates :attachment, attached: true, content_type: { in: 'application/pdf', message: 'is not a PDF' }
```

To validate size, you can add following rule.

```rb
 validates :attachment, attached: true, size: { less_than: 10.megabytes , message: 'is not given between size' }
```

To validate both content_type and size:

```rb
validates :attachment, attached: true, content_type: { in: 'application/pdf', message: 'is not a PDF' },
                                       size: { less_than: 10.megabytes , message: 'is not given between size' }
```

Take a read of https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/active_storage_validations to get more information.

Comment: i have changed that and my form too like <%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
  <%= f.submit "submit" %>
<% end %>

Comment: it shows me this error  Unknown validator: 'AttachedValidator'

Comment: can u tell how to validate size ?

Comment: sorry, did you add `active_storage_validations` gem to your Gemfile?